# How can I check the port number from $host in nginx

Tags: nginx, server

I want to check the port number in the $host variable in the https server block. How can I do that?

in the server block for port 80. I redirected to https server block for port 443. If this is the complete request `http://localhost:52379/Dika/unityphp/gateway.php`. Since port 52379 has been port forwarded to port 80, I presume the $host variable looks something like this `localhost:52379` and the request_uri is `/Dika/unityphp/gateway.php`.

```
server {
    # Configuration for port 80. Unity POB Client
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;
    index index.php index.html;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # Configuration for port 443. For https
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    include /etc/nginx/certs/self-signed.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/certs/ssl-params.conf;

    #if $host contains port number 52379 or 80 return true

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:52379;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I appreciate your assistance. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incoming requests to nginx server is defined by nginx `config` files like that one you have.

**NOTE**
if not matching blocks nginx will return `404` status code and if nginx redirected to undefined route it will return `502` status code as there not gateway

Each `server block` has it's own port by defining it using `listening' property
and each block has it's own code inside wheter you would like to redirect it or just pass localhost address of your running application on vps.

Here you are using ssl to upgrade link to https.
The default port of ssl https request is 443 and you can access it using the `servername` property you have specified.

When you create a nginx `config` file at first time the default port for it is `80` and you can change it manually.

So if you want to make diffrerent jobs based on the port you can defined multiple `server blocks` to server

or you can defined `config rules` in you `config file` like:

```bash
map $server_port $port_config {
    default       "default_config";
    80            "port_80_config";
    443           "port_443_config";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        # Use the configuration based on the port
        include $port_config;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certificate_key;

    location / {
        # Use the configuration based on the port
        include $port_config;
    }
}

# Define configurations for different ports
location @default_config {
    return 404;
}

location @port_80_config {
    # Configuration for port 80
    return 200 "This is port 80 configuration\n";
}

location @port_443_config {
    # Configuration for port 443 (HTTPS)
    return 200 "This is port 443 configuration\n";
}
```